# Howto setup second dualhead monitor to use tty10?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg

I have 2 Monitors so far setup for dual head with gnome3 using opensuse 12.2. I want the second Monitor to display the output of systemd-journalctl or htop for example on tty10 while tty7 is displaying gnome3 or any other desktop environment to work with.

1. How do i setup my both monitors like this?
2. how do i switch between them.
3. Is there a way to change between my normal setup (both monitors displaying X) and the wanted (one displaying X on tty7 and the other displaying tty10)?

I am using nvidia video card with proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run simultaneously console and X11 (or at least you should write your own code for this). My recommendation is to set your X11 with dual screen and in the second screen just put a console application with what you want in it.

In the early days (2001) I worked on a patch for mingetty to achieve that: 
 http://freecode.com/projects/mingettyfb so I have some experience regarding this.

Comment: Care to elaborate?